# database data syn error help please

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userdata(
  UID BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  Username CHAR (50) NOT NULL, 
  DisplayName CHAR (50), 
  Signature CHAR (255), 
  PRIMARY KEY(UID), 
  UNIQUE(UID,Username), 
  INDEX(UID)
)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS addressbook(
  EID BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  UID BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
  Display CHAR (50), 
  E_Mail CHAR (100) NOT NULL, 
  Info CHAR (255), 
  PRIMARY KEY(EID), 
  UNIQUE(EID), 
  INDEX(EID,UID,Display,E_Mail)
)
```

where's the error here because i cant insert in mysql

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can find the error somewhere displayed on your screen after it has occured! What does it say?

Comment: Both executed fine when I ran them

Comment: This is not a debugging service.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE addressbook( EID BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, UI' at line 10

Comment: Guessing from the error description it's probably because of a missing semicolon after the first statement. If you run both statements at once in phpmyadmin, you need to separate them by a semicolon. Or simply execute them one at a time and it should work fine.

Comment: so how to fix the missing statement ?

Comment: @IskonoMorto As I said, just put a semicolon (;) after the first statement (or even better after each statement). Look at Ike Walkers answer. Just copy/paste it and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a semi-colon after each separate SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userdata(
  UID BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  Username CHAR (50) NOT NULL, 
  DisplayName CHAR (50), 
  Signature CHAR (255), 
  PRIMARY KEY(UID), 
  UNIQUE(UID,Username), 
  INDEX(UID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS addressbook(
  EID BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  UID BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
  Display CHAR (50), 
  E_Mail CHAR (100) NOT NULL, 
  Info CHAR (255), 
  PRIMARY KEY(EID), 
  UNIQUE(EID), 
  INDEX(EID,UID,Display,E_Mail)
);
```